# How to test a scrollTop event in Angular 8 with Jest?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, undefined, scrolltop

I've been searching for a solution to test the scrollTop event for two days, but I haven't found a solution anywhere. All my attempts returned the same error ...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of undefined
```

**header.component.ts**

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onWindowScroll(): void {       
  if(document.scrollingElement.scrollTop > 63){
    this.headerElement.classList.add('height-63');
  }else{
    this.headerElement.classList.remove('height-63');
  }
}
```

**header.component.spec**

```
it('should test scrollTop', () => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 500);
  //document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = 500 --> I already tried to set the scrollTop value
  fixture.detectChanges();
  component.onWindowScroll();    
  expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.height-63')).toBeTruthy();    
});
```

Comment: what is it - component ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok friends, I found a solution!
The way I was doing it was impossible to continue ... So I decided to change the way I was checking the scroll and it worked!

I change

```
if(document.scrollingElement.scrollTop > 63)
```

To

```
if(window.pageYOffset > 63)
```

The result was this:

**header.component.ts**

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onWindowScroll(): void {       
  if(window.pageYOffset > 63){
    this.headerElement.classList.add('height-63');
  }else{
    this.headerElement.classList.remove('height-63');
  }
}
```

**header.component.spec**

```
it('should test HostListener', () => {
  component.onWindowScroll();
  expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.height-63')).not.toBeTruthy();
  window = Object.assign(window, { pageYOffset: 100 });
  component.onWindowScroll();
  expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.height-63')).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Thanks!